# Brew install fails with 403 Unauthorized

Tags: homebrew

Despite having installed other packages successfully with brew, I am unable to install maven.

After running `brew install maven`, I get the following error:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with 9103121 bytes remaining to read
Error: maven: Failed to download resource "maven"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/maven/blobs/sha256:ff38bb52b93216582dbd13fb00be5679090ac4b66f7e7c5c8cae5f70626238bb
```

I am using the following versions of brew and git:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 3.3.8
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 7c983d9c784; last commit 2021-12-13)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 538992b1fb; last commit 2021-12-13)
$ git --version
git version 2.23.0
```

When visiting the failed download in my browser, I also get a 403 failure:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required"}]}
```

This error is strange to me because I would not think brew dependencies for public taps like for maven would require authorization.

Comment: Of note, I installed brew without sudo privileges using the following command:
`mkdir $HOME/homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C $HOME/homebrew`

Answer (score 3):

My work network/VPN was causing this error. I was able to download successfully disabling my VPN and using my mobile network connection.

Comment: how to resolve this if I can't disable my work network vpn? We are required to connect to work vpn all for any work related stuff.

Comment: You’ll want to notify your IT team that certain downloads are getting blocked. I did the same at my company.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to install OpenJDK through brew even after trying a lot of times. In the end it just gave me a error stating as Unauthorized request. This might be linked to the fact that from the past few years if you have to download OpenJDK from Oracle, then its necessary for you to have a account on Oracle.

So if you are also someone who is not able to install OpenJDK through HomeBrew I would recommend you to install OpenJDK through official website https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/. For downloading it from the official website, you will need to have a Oracle Account.