# Brew install poppler got curl 403

Tags: curl, homebrew, glib, poppler

Trying to install **poppler** on m1 using `brew install poppler`; all dependencies are downloaded fine apart from `glib` which gave a `curl 403 error`.

> "Error: poppler: Failed to download resource "glib".
>
> Download failed: [https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.72/glib-2.72.2.tar.xz"](https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.72/glib-2.72.2.tar.xz%22)

This is odd as I can manually download from the link; not sure why got a 403.
Did find this thread: [Brew install fails with 403 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338745/brew-install-fails-with-403-unauthorized)
but can't use its solution as I can't disable my work network vpn.

Any other way to get around this?
If not, how to install a package with brew using a manually downloaded dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact reason but I suspect it's due to company network setting.

In the end I found a way to get around this since I can manually download glib source code. Then use `mv glib-2.72.2.tar.xz $(brew --cache -s glib)` to move it to the homebrew cache. Then install poppler as normal e.g. `brew install poppler` it will mark glib as already downloaded.

Hope this helps someone.